# removing the extra input inside a v-select in vuetify

Tags: html, vue.js, select, vuetify.js, v-select

My v-select has an extra input inside it which makes the styling very problematic. My custom component doesn't add it. I am pretty sure it's some vuetify stuff. Does anybody know how to get rid of it?[image]

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, there isn't a Vuetify prop to remove it, but you can set it's display as `none`.

If you want to remove it globally you can just add this selector to your main style file:

```css
.v-select .v-select__selections input {
    display: none;
}
```

You can specify it by selector or even use `::v-deep` if you're in a scoped style tag.

Answer (score 0):

If this still helps you:

```
.custom-v-select::v-deep input {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: The `::v-deep` syntax is deprecated in last version of vue-js, you should use `:deep(.custom-v-select input)` syntax when used in scoped css.